# Does sliding on ice count as walking?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I am trying to friendship grind my eevee so I can get an umbreon in Pokémon Silver. One of the easiest ways of doing so is by walking back and forth for a long time. This method does take a while because the friendship level only changes by +1 every 512 steps.

The Friendship Checker in Goldenrod City said my eevee is "friendly towards me" so I had a bit of grinding to do.

I found a large patch of ice in [B2F of Ice Path](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ice_Path#Layout) while playing through casually. I figured the higher than usual walk speeds on ice would make an easy grinding session, but after what seemed like a while, the Friendship Checker said the same thing.

I've looked around the internet, but I can't find anything related to steps on ice. Does sliding on ice count as walking? Am I gaining *any* friendship at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to two answers on [Pokemondb](https://pokemondb.net/pokebase/154428/does-sliding-across-ice-count-as-one-step), sliding on ice does **not** count as taking steps, and therefore ice skating is not progressing your friendship.

Comment: *therefore ice skating is not progressing your friendship* - I love the words Pokémon make us say.